# Is there a way to insert custom _id value via meteor autoform?

Tags: mongodb, meteor, meteor-autoform, meteor-collection2, simple-schema

Using aldeed-autoform for inserting automatically generates a _id field while storing in mongo. I'm interested in knowing if this _id field can be opened up as a text box where in the user is allowed  to input a unique id instead if it being randomly auto generated.

Example:

```
{
  _id:{
    type: String,
    autoform:{
      type:"select",
    ...
    ...
    ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried it?  It might just "work".

Comment: Yes, should work! The insert would fail if it wasn't unique however but you could build checking around that.

Comment: Goodness me. It works just like any other form field.